# Script permissions and merging cells based on content of another cell

Tags: google-apps-script, merge, permissions, google-sheets, conditional-statements

I'm making a google sheet that I need two adjacent cells to merge having the left one take over the right, basically hiding the right, with its content. I need them to merge depending on if a specific =SEARCH is found in the left cell. I found plenty on formatting two together if they're the same value, but not much on formatting dependent on a completely different cell.

Second half of my question that I can't find is that this sheet will be used at work where we have a google organization account that doesn't seem to let me create scripts. But if I make the script on a personal account bound to the sheet then share it, does the sheet no longer use the script?

I wrote this script

```
function JMerge(x,y) {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

 // The code below will merge cells C5:E5 into one cell
 var range1 = sheet.getRange("x:y");
 range1.mergeAcross();
}
```

Only issue is that when I run it, in my personal google drive, I get ERROR " You do not have permission to call MergeAcross()"

Ideas?

Comment: This appears to be something to sort out with Google domain admin. I don't have any problem running mergeAcross in my personal account; there must be something up with the sheet you are trying to run this on.

Comment: When you run it are you can't the function from a cell?

Comment: So, you are trying to do this from a custom function. They can't edit a spreadsheet, they only read and return data to the place they are called from. See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#using_apps_script_services

Comment: So if I wanted this script to fire when it sees a specific letter in a cell how would I do that?

Comment: You'll need to use an installable trigger running on every edit and checking whether it was to a cell of interest, and what the new value is.

Comment: so i've seen the command onedit, do i write a new script and install that script?

Comment: An installable trigger, not a simple onEdit trigger.

Comment: where do i do an installable trigger?

Answer (score 0):

`"x:y"` in A1 notation refers to the whole columns X and Y, not to cells C5:E5 as the comment in the code describe.

I don't know if this could cause the problem but, according to the comment it will not return the intended result.

As the function have x,y as arguments is very likely that

```
var range1 = sheet.getRange("x:y");
```

should be replaced by something like

```
var range1 = sheet.getRange(x,y);
```

but you should be sure that x and y are valid integers.

Comment: Ahhh, that makes sense. I was trying to pass variables in from calling the function. Although now it looks like I can't call a function to a sheet.